# EclEmma plugin with TestNG plugin and multiple eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, testng, emma

I have ten maven modules, which are separate eclipse projects. All of them has testNG tests.
When I trying to create emma coverage configuration for this it allows choose only one particular project. So, to receive the whole picture of main project coverage I have to create 10 emma coverage configurations! 
It's very inconvenient both in configuring and using, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Note that it's also valuable to know the coverage of each project's unit tests individually, since unit tests ideally focus on units within a project.

Comment: @Andy technically these projects are only parts of main project, so for me it's nothing interesting in coverage of particular module...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation, in our scenario we had multiple projects and they all had junits, we created a another project which had test configurations and TestSuite to include junits test cases for all the projects. Running TestSuite would give us coverage for all the projects.

Though you have maven but you can use similar design.

Hoping this suggestion helps you.

Cheers !!